# AngularJS - How to refer transcluded element in the link function

Tags: angularjs

Here's the link to the source code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OrdlKQGroRGk6q0AKeLI?p=preview.
I have created two directives in a parent-child relation. The child directive has an `ng-repeat` associated with it. As `ng-repeat` has a priority of 1000, I had to increase the priority of the child directive so that the link function of `my-child-directive` is called first followed by `my-parent-directive`.Inside the child directive's link function, I am using transclusion to add the compiled elements.
**Question:** Is there any way to get the reference of the transcluded <div> elements through ng-repeat?

Comment: Are you trying to register all ng-repeat elements that are there after the directive was compiled? It doesn't seem to be a good choice, because the feature of ng-repeat is that its elements aren't static and their composite can be changed on another digest.

Comment: yes @estuary. I want to get a hold of all the elements rendered by ng-repeat. in my case the elements that ng-repeat be static. Is there any solution to achieve this in my case?